# Why Meyer's Singleton method is not thread-safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, singleton, c++14

I have read from many discussions that Meyers Singleton provides thread safety. To see that, I wrote a simple code as follows in C++14.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class SingletonClass {
 public:
       static SingletonClass& Instance() {
           static SingletonClass instance;
           return instance;
       }
       
       void task1() {
           for (int i = 0; i < 50000; ++i)
               a++;
       }
       int getA() {return a;}

   private:
       SingletonClass()= default;
       ~SingletonClass()= default;
       SingletonClass(const SingletonClass&)= delete;
       SingletonClass& operator=(const SingletonClass&)= delete;

       int a;
};

void callSingleton() {
   SingletonClass::Instance().task1();
}

int main() {
   std::thread t1(callSingleton);
   std::thread t2(callSingleton);
   
   t1.join();
   t2.join();

   std::cout << "a: " << SingletonClass::Instance().getA() << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

I expect that *a* should be 100000 because this class is thread-safe. However, I cannot get 100000 value for *a*. I don't realize why this doesn't work if Meyers Singleton is thread-safe. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your Meyers singleton **access** is thread-safe.  Threads can not violate that it is a singleton.  The object retrieved, however, is not automatically made thread-safe.

Answer (score 4):

Because of data race in `a`.

```
void task1() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; ++i){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mLock);
        a++;
    }
}
```

or define

```
atomic<int> a;
```

For both, I get 100000.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I agree with these solutions, I tried them too and get 100000. However, the confusing part for me is how I can use thread-safe feature of this Singleton class if I cannot use it like that. From thread-safe, I understand that multiple threads should not modify the data at the same time, but here I cannot get the point of thread-safety of Meyers Singleton

Comment: @finesttea From my understanding, the class has deleted copy constructor and deleted copy assignment, and private constructor. `static SingletonClass instance` makes sure that only one object is created and immediately returned. If the first thread creates the object, the second one will just return it without creating a new one. The thread-safe is in terms of accessing the object, not the members in the class.